# `PyTuple_Pack` segfault

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, python-extensions

I have a function `foo` in a Python Extension Module that should return a tuple of ints to Python. This can be easily done using `Py_BuildValue`:

```
static PyObject* 
foo(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    /* calculations and stuff */

    PyObject* out = Py_BuildValue("(iii)", a, b, a+b);
    Py_INCREF(out);

    return out;
}
```

Instead of `Py_BuildValue`, I want to use `PyTuple_Pack`, which ensures that the return value is indeed a tuple.

The [Python C API documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_Pack) says that `PyTuple_Pack(3, a, b, a+b)` is equivalent to `Py_BuildValue("(iii)", a, b, a+b)`. Both functions return a new reference of type `PyPbject*`.

Hence, given the code above,

```
static PyObject* 
foo(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    /* ... */

    PyObject* out = PyTuple_Pack(3, a, b, a+b);
    Py_INCREF(out);

    return out;
}
```

should do the trick, which is does not. Instead I get a segfault.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is:

- `Py_BuildValue("(ii)", a, b)` expects `a` and `b` to be simple C-int values.
- `PyTuple_Pack(2, a, b)` expects `a` and  `b` to be already `PyObject`s (and not C-ints).

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_Pack) says:

> The tuple values are initialized to the subsequent n C arguments pointing to **Python objects**. `PyTuple_Pack(2, a, b)` is equivalent to `Py_BuildValue("(OO)", a, b)`.

In order to use `PyTuple_Pack` you need to convert the int-values to Python-Integers first.

It is simpler to use `Py_BuildValue()`. If you parenthesize your format string in [`Py_BuildValue`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue), the result will be a tuple:

> `Py_BuildValue()` does not always build a tuple. It builds a tuple only if its format string contains two or more format units. If the format string is empty, it returns None; if it contains exactly one format unit, it returns whatever object is described by that format unit. **To force it to return a tuple of size 0 or one, parenthesize the format string**.

That means: there is nothing to worry about if you construct a tuple from at least two elements:

```
Py_BuildValue("ii", a, b)   # returns a tuple
Py_BuildValue("(ii)", a, b) # returns a tuple
```

It is different if there is only one element:

```
Py_BuildValue("i", a)    # returns an integer
# parenthesized:
Py_BuildValue("(i)", a)  # returns a tuple with an integer
```

or no elements at all:

```
Py_BuildValue("")    # returns None
# parenthesized:
Py_BuildValue("()")  # returns an empty tuple.
```

So just make sure there are parenthesizes in the format string and the returned value will be a tuple.